# How to redirect to specific session in aplication?

Tags: java, html, jsp

I want redirect my application to specific section after save some values in database. Something like response.sendRedirect("my section in html").
How I can do this?

Comment: What you mean saying `session in html`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant section .

Comment: I try response.sendRedirect(main.jsp#settings) and works fine. Thank you for the answer.